# UITextField not working properly within UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm having an issues while integrating `UITextfield` as a subview in `UITableViewCell`. I have used the following code in my project to add `UITextField` as a subView within `UITableViewCell`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.row==languageName) {
        if (langNameTxtFld==nil) {
            langNameTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            langNameTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:langNameTxtFld placeholder:@"Language Name" returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==region) {
            if (regionTxtFld==nil) {

            regionTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            regionTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:regionTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"region_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        } 
        else if (indexPath.row==city) {
            if (cityTxtFld==nil) {

            cityTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            cityTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:cityTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"city_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==school) {
            if (schoolsTxtFld==nil) {

            schoolsTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            schoolsTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:schoolsTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"schools_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==studies){
            if (studiesTxtFld==nil) {

            studiesTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            studiesTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:studiesTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"studies_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==email) {
            if (emailTxtFld==nil) {

            emailTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            emailTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:emailTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"email"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }

        else if (indexPath.row==passwords){
            if (passwordsTxtFld==nil) {

            passwordsTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            passwordsTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:passwordsTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"passwords"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

> For Adding TextField into Table Cell i have used custom function as follows

```
 -(id)addTextFieldWithText:(NSString*)text textField:(id)txtFld placeholder:(NSString*)placeholder returnType:(UIReturnKeyType)keyType {
    [txtFld setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [txtFld setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [txtFld setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [txtFld setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [txtFld setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [txtFld setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];
    [txtFld setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [txtFld setReturnKeyType:keyType];
    [txtFld setPlaceholder:placeholder]; 
    [txtFld setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]];
    return txtFld;
}
```

Above code has worked fine and i got the output tableview as follows 
[image: UITextField within UITableView]

[image: UITextField responding to textFieldShouldBeginEditing]

But when i tried to scroll the UITableView the placeholder values in UITextField get's collapsed and it displays as follows
[image: Placeholder get collapsed]

At the same time when i tried to type in textField  the text has been overlapped with the placeholder text as follows
[image: placeholder text overlaps with textfield text]

So anyone having idea about this please help me to get out of this issue.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You have programmed in wrong way.

You are creating cell once and allocation text fields again and again, so they are overriding on each other.

There are 2 options to solve this issue :-

1. You can create custom cell class and declare all text fields there and just pass values here.
2. You need to create cell every time.

Hope this solution helps you.

If you are opting for 2 one

Here is code :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (indexPath.row==languageName) {
        if (langNameTxtFld==nil) {
            langNameTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            langNameTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:langNameTxtFld placeholder:@"Language Name" returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==region) {
            if (regionTxtFld==nil) {

            regionTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            regionTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:regionTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"region_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        } 
        else if (indexPath.row==city) {
            if (cityTxtFld==nil) {

            cityTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            cityTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:cityTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"city_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==school) {
            if (schoolsTxtFld==nil) {

            schoolsTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            schoolsTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:schoolsTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"schools_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==studies){
            if (studiesTxtFld==nil) {

            studiesTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            studiesTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:studiesTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"studies_meaning"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==email) {
            if (emailTxtFld==nil) {

            emailTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            emailTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:emailTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"email"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }

        else if (indexPath.row==passwords){
            if (passwordsTxtFld==nil) {

            passwordsTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
            passwordsTxtFld.delegate=self;
            [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:passwordsTxtFld placeholder:[globalPlaceHolderDict valueForKeyPath:@"passwords"] returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
            }
        }
    }
}
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said option 2 may help let me code and update the answer..

Comment: I have implemented the same code you mentioned, but now the placeholder values repeated i.e langaugename, region,city,schools,studies,email again the same order repeating... then placeholders get collapsed when i scroll the tableview, the output which is similar to the picture 3 in my question.

Comment: its better if you go for first solution I mentioned above

Comment: [link to the code](http://www.4shared.com/photo/W-CaSJuy/TextEdit.html) click on the link to see the code which i used for option 1 but it's also results in the same output which i got earlier..

Answer (score 0):

As P.J indicated, The problem is, you are adding textfield to a cell that already had textfield resulting in the effect you see.

You can easily fix this using

1. Add a TAG field to the textfield when you add it as a subview and then remove the that textfield using the tag everytime when you reuse a cell

In your header declare

```
#define MY_CUSTOM_TAG "MY_CUSTOM_TAG"


if (cell==nil) 
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
else
{
   // Clear the old textfield before reusing it
   [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG]removeFromSuperview] ;
}

 if (indexPath.row==languageName) {
  if (langNameTxtFld==nil) {
    langNameTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 265, 44)];
    langNameTxtFld.delegate=self;
    langNameTxtFld.tag = MY_CUSTOM_TAG; // Set a tag so it can be later found and removed for reusing this cell
    [cell addSubview:[self addTextFieldWithText:nil textField:langNameTxtFld placeholder:@"Language Name" returnType:UIReturnKeyNext]];
    }
    }
.

.
```